# Twig 2 Arrays & For loop

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, loops, twig

I have 2 different arrays that i want to loop.
The arrays are the same length, since an address has 1 balance.

```
{% for address in addresses %}
  <input value="{{ address }}">

  {% for balance in balances %}
    <p>{{balance|number_format(10, '.', ',')}} BTC / 0.00 USD</p>
  {% endfor %}

{% else %}
<p>No addresses found!</p>
{% endfor %}
```

[This is the result...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfG2Y.png) (the balance should of course only be printed once "per address")

Here's how it's rendered from the Controller:

```
return $this->render(
    'wallet/index.html.twig', 
            [
                'addresses' =>  $aAddresses,
                'balances' => $aAddressBalances,
            ]);
```

[and the values in the arrays here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca4Wb.png)

What am i missing, and what's the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if addresses|length != 0 %}

  {% set counter= 0 %}
  {% for address in addresses %}
    <input value="{{ address }}">

    <p>{{balances[counter]|number_format(10, '.', ',')}} BTC / 0.00 USD</p>
    {% set counter= counter+1 %}
  {% endfor %}
{% else %}
  <p>No addresses found!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: The last iteration gives the following error:
Key "16" for array with keys "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15" does not exist.

Comment: I have mapped the arrays together using array_map, would that elimate the need for the counter? https://imgur.com/a/L2qUvxr

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to map the 2 arrays using

```
array_map(null, $array1, $array2);
```

then in the twig loop:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ address[0] }}">
<p>{{address[1]|number_format(10, '.', ',')}} BTC / 0.00 USD</p>
```

Since address[0] is the address & address[1] is the balance.